# Diode circuit analysis problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

Again, I have a problem with solving diode circuit (I have an upcoming exam and the courseware is pretty bad and the teacher doesn't want to help)
I am not sure how to handle the 5; 4,5; and 6 V sources, in a parallel circuit the voltages are the same right?
I know that the diodes have a potential of 0,7V so that makes:
-> 5V -0,7V = 4,3V
->4,5V -0,7V = 3,8V
-> 6V -0,7V = 5,3V

So what's the potential over R1? -5V or 0V?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Since the cathodes of the diodes are at the same potential, only one of them will be ON. Work your way from there.

Comment: You also need to decide where ground is.

Comment: So does that mean you always need to use the one with the highest potential?

Comment: As Scott Seidman has pointed out, you need a ground reference (or the voltages in the question are meaningless). The arrow with the "U" seems to have been carelessly drawn. Is that intended to show the voltage across R1 (since that is what the question is asking) or the voltage between the two horizontal "rails" in the diagram? V2 seems to be unusual in it's placement and purpose. Is the + side of V2 intended to be ground? If not, it would seem to have no purpose in this diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very strange question. I hop it will work in this way.

Only 6V pin supply will passed through the diode to give a 5.3V. This 5.3V will reverse bias other diodes and they wont conduct.

voltage across R1 will be `5.3 - (-5) = 10.3V`

Comment: I thought the voltage across R1 was 0,3. Why is it 10,3V?

Comment: @Sanu: Welcome to EE.SE. We discourage providing complete answers to homework questions. Instead, you should give a comment (when you have enough rep) or an answer that points them in the right direction without giving a complete solution.

Comment: 5V supply is inversely connected to ground. So one end of the resistor have **-5V** (not 5v) so total difference will be 10.3V

Comment: @user120399: Redraw your circuit in your original post with CircuitLab, call the bottom rail ground and apply "nodes" to each circuit element and enter the voltage value into each node. It should become obvious.

Comment: @transistor : i am sorry about this, and i am new to this platform

Comment: @Sanu-OpenMaker  -- we have no way of knowing where ground is.